# Is there any way to set severity/priority to steps in Allure?

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, allure

I want to mark steps of my tests as "normal", "major", "critical", etc., like  @Severity for test methods. Is there any way to realize it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can add the Severity only for @Test, not for steps. That even makes sense to focus globally on the test rather than each step.

Priority is something which says from which test we should start at the beginning. However, this is also something which we would like to avoid in automation testing. When using test runners like JUnit or TestNG you cannot be 100% sure what will be the order of tests.

Anyway, if you like to use Severity for Tests, here is the code ;)

```
import static io.qameta.allure.Allure.step;

@Test
@Severity(SeverityLevel.CRITICAL)
public void test1_login () throws TestException {

   step("Login to app");
   LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(super.driver,20);
   loginPage.login();

   step("Open main page");
}
```

It will result in adding the information as below:

[image]